Movie about a father and his 2 sons
I am trying to help my friend to find a movie she saw long ago. This is what she told me about "the mysterious" film:

It's American, years 2005-2011... 2 brothers and father were living in the USA, in some little town. Each of them had their own stuff (the father was going to work, I think he was working at some college, the little brother was going to kindergarten, and the older brother to school)
The father was divorced. But in the movie their mother had her "moments"
They had a mess in their house
The little brother was talking with some young woman on internet (she of course was thinking he was as old as her) so they decided to meet in the park
And they met. She was waiting for him, he came, but she thought he wasn't that person who she knew from the internet.

I guess it's something along those lines. I hope you guys can help.

What genre was it? ( drama, comedy ,etc). Do you recall any of the actors, was it an indie film?

This is most definitely "Me and You and Everyone We Know"... it's been awhile since I saw it, but it's got the brothers, and the unforgettable scene in which the younger brother meets the woman in the park.

This is the movie. Thank you very much!
